# 1С: привязка сообщения к строке табличной части, когда номер строки больше 999-1000

Tags: 1с

Требуется во время проверок выводить сообщения с привязкой к строке, однако когда строк более 999-1000, то привязки к 1001 строке и далее нет. Она либо слетает на угол таблицы, либо на верхние строки (у меня на указание 1001 строки привязка слезла аж на строку 2).
[image: Указывает совсем не на ту строку]
Код вывода сообщения:

```
Сообщение = Новый СообщениеПользователю();
Сообщение.Текст = ТекстОшибки;
Сообщение.Поле = ТЧ[НомерСтроки-1].Колонка1; 
Сообщение.УстановитьДанные(ЭтотОбъект);
Сообщение.Сообщить();
```

Сколько ищу, никак не могу найти ответ, как это исправить. Знаю только, что это возможно, и это с меня требуют. Что нужно указать и где, чтобы все работа исправно при таких огромных количествах строк?

Answer (score 1):

Решено!

```
Сообщение.Поле = "Объект.Тч[НомерСтроки-1].Колонка1";
```

Comment: Если есть БСП, можно еще так:

`Текст = НСтр("ru='Текст ошибки'");
Поле = ОбщегоНазначенияКлиентСервер.ПутьКТабличнойЧасти("Объект.ТЧ", Выборка.НомерСтроки, "НомерСтроки");
ОбщегоНазначения.СообщитьПользователю(Текст, , Поле);`